# How to get refreshToken in MSAL login for IOS

Tags: swift, azure-ad-msal

I am struggling to integrate AD login in my application. its succeeding and returning the response to the app. but now i need refreshToken as well with authToken but till now i didNot succeed to get value of refreshToken,

methods i tried:

- acquireTokenSilently
- acquireToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL obtains refresh tokens together with access tokens and caches them to later retrieve new access tokens during `acquireTokenSilent`. If `MSALError.interactionRequired` is thrown during the former then you should call `acquireTokenInteractively` in order to obtain new tokens.

Take a look to the following sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-mobile-apple-swift-objc/blob/7bd269510b8d07f59a10363b326962898c4fc106/MSALiOS/ViewController.swift#L188

Comment: Hey, i have a requirement, where i need refresh token to pass on to some other API. Can you please let me know how will i get? @AlfredoRevilla-MSFT

Comment: Any luck retrieving the refresh token (or at least some meaningful info why it is not present)?

Answer (score 2):

For the record - MSAL **does NOT expose a `refresh_token`**, it is private to the library, you need to use the account to refresh the `access_token` - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/1671#issuecomment-1481876126